# Spring MVC: how to display the output of different controllers on the home page?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller, mapping, aggregate

From my understanding, each controller or controller methods is mapped to a different url, for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/news", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestMapping(value="/comments", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

I am wondering if there's a way to display the output of different controller methods on the same page (e.g. home page), because a typical web page shows different categories of contents.

Comment: Call the underlying service methods directly and aggregate the results. Alternatively, you could do this with javascript or frames.

Comment: yes its possible .. Cumulation of data can be handled using AJAX call .. Load the jsp and in the <head> call different controller's url using AJAX .. accomplish this by jQuery

Comment: thanks, but I would rather take AJAX as my last resort in achieving this. If there's an easier alternative way to aggregate the results, that'll be perfect

Comment: @TonyGW Your `/` method should probably call the same service methods as each of these other controller methods. There's not any other shortcut; this isn't a super-common problem and not something for which it is easy to write a generic solution.

Comment: @beerbajay, you mean I should use **/*** as a wildcard to call all the controllers that I want to aggregate on the same page? thanks

Comment: No, you should have a method annotated with `@RequestMapping(value="/")` which should then call `service.getNews()`, `service.getComments()` etc.